# Write a program for $\{Q: x= A \wedge y=B\}\ ord2\ \{R: x\leqslant y \wedge [(x=A\wedge y=B)\vee(x=B \wedge y=A)]\}$ specification

Tags: algorithms

I need to develop a program with the following specification:

$$\{Q: x= A \wedge y=B\}\ ord2\ \{R: x\leqslant y \wedge [(x=A\wedge y=B)\vee(x=B \wedge y=A)]\}$$

**Solution:**

What I understand is to develop a program which sorts the both input values -$x$ and $y$- such as $x$ is always less than or equal to $y$ at the end of the program (post-condition $Q$).

This is my first attempt (it's written in GCL):

$[\text{Ctx}\ C: x,y\in \mathrm{Z}$

$\{Q: x= A \wedge y=B\}$

$if\ x > y \rightarrow $

$\ \ \ \ temp := x;$

$\ \ \ \ x := y;$

$\ \ \ \ y := temp;$

$else $

$\ \ \ \ skip;$

$\{R: x\leqslant y \wedge [(x=A\wedge y=B)\vee(x=B \wedge y=A)]\}$

$]$

Is it correct?